# What is the stylus equivalent for expanding properties as with sass?

Tags: stylus

A simple snippet on sass, which uses a nesting for expanding css properties, `font-size` and `font-weight`.

```
p
  color: red
  font:
    size: 12px
    weight: bold
```

which gets compiled into,

```
p {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

the stylus code,

```
p
  color red
  font
    size 12px
    weight bold
```

gets compiled into,

```
p {
  color: #f00;
}
p font {
  size: 12px;
  weight: bold;
}
```

How can I make stylus to compile the properties as sass do, than repeating the property names ?

thanks.

Comment: I didn't even knew that SASS expand properties. Can't you use the real CSS property names instead?

Comment: There seems not to be such flexibility as stated in documentations, although documents are limited and many stuff are just has be be tested

Comment: @feeela No I can't! I'm lazy and Pythonist ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such native feature in Stylus (see https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/848), but you can somehow emulate it using custom mixins like this one:

```
font(options = {})
  if typeof(options) == 'object'
    default = {
      family: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
      size: 1em
      height: 1.25
      weight: unquote('')
    }
    options = merge(default, options)

    font: s(
      '%s %s/%s %s',
      options.weight,
      options.size,
      options.height,
      unquote(join(', ', options.family)))
  else
    font: arguments

.foo
  font({
    family: Arial sans-serif
    size: 10px
    weight: bold
  })
```

Here we're creating a transparent `font` mixin which takes an `options` object, which is when defined would be merged with the predefined default font values and then rendered as a single `font` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in official documentations. But according to this [Link](http://designshack.net/articles/css/sass-vs-stylus-who-wins-the-minimal-syntax-battle/), Sass has the cool feature of nesting properties but Stylus does not provide such thing.
Instead I propose You could use a custom mixin for the situation.